# No se puede seleccionar la base de datos Wordpress en WampServer

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, wamp

He descargado directamente de la página https://es-mx.wordpress.org/ para descomprimir dentro de mi carpeta raíz de Wamp Server (www), después de crear mi base de datos con usuario root (todos los privilegios) en phpmyadmin y entrar a localhost/wordpress para instalarlo, no puede pasar del siguiente mensaje:

```
Hemos podido conectar con el servidor de la base de datos (lo que significa 
que tu nombre de usuario y contraseña son correctos), pero no ha sido 
posible seleccionar la base de datos virtualgame.

¿Estás seguro de que existe?
¿Tiene el usuario root permiso para usar la base de datos virtualgame?
En algunos sistemas, el nombre de tu base de datos tiene el prefijo de tu 
nombre de usuario, por lo que sería algo como nombreusuario_virtualgame. 
¿Podría ser ese el problema?
```

Buscando en foros encontré que debo sustituir en el archivo "wp-config-sample" en la información

```
 define('DB_NAME', 'nombredetubasededatos');

 /** Tu nombre de usuario de MySQL */
 define('DB_USER', 'nombredeusuario');

 /** Tu contraseña de MySQL */
 define('DB_PASSWORD', 'contraseña');

 /** Host de MySQL (es muy probable que no necesites cambiarlo) */
 define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
```

**Pero aunque haga esto, me muestra el mismo mensaje.**

Nota: La contraseña la dejo vacía debido a que mi usuario root para PHPMYAdmin no la tiene.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Una vez que realizas los cambios en wp-config-sample es necesario reiniciar el servidor. Descartemos, hiciste esto y no pasa nada?

Comment: Así es @Mani sigue mostrandome el mensaje aun cuando aplico restart a los servicios de wampserver.

Comment: Perdon, lo que hiciste en wp-config-sample debes hacerlo en wp-config.php (es el archivo que esta al lado, si ordenas alfabeticamente). Ahi tambien modificaste  DB_NAME, DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD Y DB_HOST?

Comment: ¿Cuando dices PHPMYAdmin te refieres a MySQL? ¿Has probado a entrar directamente desde phpmyadmin en la base de datos con los datos que tienes? ¿Has probado a usar la línea de comandos para conectar con la base de datos?

Comment: Estoy entrando directamente a PHPMyAdmin donde cree la bdd con el usuario root @track3r

Comment: @Mani el archivo " wp-config.php" no existe en la última versión de wordpress, es la que descargue directamente de la página.

Comment: Las credenciales correctas tienen que estar sí o sí en el archivo **`wp-config.php`**. Que yo sepa WP no ha prescindido de ese archivo, que es el que indica a qué base de datos se conectará tu WP, con qué usuario y con qué contraseña. Revisa eso y verifica qué datos hay allí.

Comment: @A. Cedano como repito esta última versión únicamente contiene el archivo "wp-config-sample.php" y no "wp-config.php" incluso si le quito "-sample" ni siquiera me deja entrar al instalador por que dice "Me hace falta el archivo wp-config-sample.php".

Comment: @A. Cedano https://es-mx.wordpress.org

Comment: No importa, es el mismo Wordpress. [Lee las instrucciones](https://es-mx.wordpress.org/txt-install/). Habla claramente del archivo `wp-config.php`. Si no te funciona es porque algún error cometiste al instalar o algo.

Comment: El fichero wp-config-sample.php es un ejemplo para que copies en el fichero wp-config.php, no borres el sample, simplemente copia a wp-config.php y modifica a tu gusto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me ha funcionado hacer lo siguiente:

1. Iniciar servicios de wamp server.
2. Navega a la carpeta C:\wamp\Apache2\conf en el disco duro principal de tu servidor o en la unidad en la que WAMP ha sido instalado previamente.
3. Busca el archivo que tiene la etiqueta "http.conf" y haz doble clic en éste para abrirlo en la aplicación del Bloc de notas de Windows.
4. Pulsa las teclas "control" y "F" al mismo tiempo para iniciar la utilidad de búsqueda.
5. Escribe "80" en el campo de búsqueda y pulsa "Buscar siguiente". Esto te llevará a la parte del archivo de configuración donde se encuentra el puerto localhost.
6. Cambia a "8080" el puerto encontrado y luego guarda el archivo "http.conf" para actualizar el servidor. Es posible que debas reiniciar el servidor para que el nuevo puerto sea reconocido.

Comment: Si añades como hiciste el cambio que mencionas dando una orientación, no solo sería mas claro tu aporte sino que quedaría como una buena guía para otros y otras.

Comment: @Aprendiz listo maestro.

Answer (score 0):

A mi el cambio de 80 a 8080 no me funcionó.

La solución que encontré es que tenía creada la BBDD en el *servidor MySQL* y hay que **crearla en MariaDB**.

En cuanto estuvo lista en MariaDB, la instalación fue sin problema.

Dejo una imagen de como acceder. También se puede seleccionar directamente al hacer loguearse.

Espero que les sirva.

[image: Servidores de BBDD en phpMyAdmin]

Answer (score -1):

Intenta entrando al phpmyadmin y settear una contraseña para root, algunas veces las aplicaciones requieren de una contraseña pre-establecida (no vacías).

Comment: No me funcionó amigo, incluso si creo un nuevo usuario con todos los privilegios (con contraseña) y creo la base de datos, me sigue mostrando "Hemos podido conectar con el servidor de la base de datos (lo que significa que tu nombre de usuario y contraseña son correctos), pero no ha sido posible seleccionar la base de datos mydbname".

Comment: podrías enseñar una imagen del phpmyadmin mostrando la base de datos virtualgaming, otra en la pestaña de configuración de los usuarios y otra de la configuración de la base de datos. Adicionalmente puedes descartar que no sea un problema de permisos: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database.table TO 'user'@'localhost';

Comment: @ Isaac Vásquez Listo, la imágen esta en la pregunta.

Comment: En el nombre del servidor de root: cambia localhost por %. También puedes intentar cambiar localhost en DB_HOST por 127.0.0.1. **Asegúrese** además de haber cambiado wp-config-sample.php a wp-config.php

Comment: @Issac Vásquez Sigue sin reconocerlo, incluso cree un nuevo usuario con todos los privilegios y asignando "%" en nombre del host. Aunado a esto he sustituido en el archivo "wp-config-sample" la información que me solicita en la información de wordpress y sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: Cambiaste wp-config-sample.php a wp-config.php  ??

Comment: no, lo deje así por que así viene directamente de la descarga.

Comment: Cambialo, los archivos "sample" son archivos ejemplos de configuración, no la configuración como tal.

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/189726)

Comment: @Isaac Vásquez si cambio el nombre del archivo "wp-config-sample" por solo "wp-config" ni siquiera me carga el instalador de wordpress

Comment: @DjCrazy qué hice mal? Si aún no resuelvo mi pregunta

Comment: Suri, el comentario no va para ti sino para @IsaacVásquez . La respuesta que ofrece parece más un comentario ya que, como tu mismo lo acabas de decir, no resuelve tu pregunta y se está extendiendo demasiado en comentarios de aclaración. Lo que trato de hacer, es orientar a Isaac para que sus respuestas sean de mayor calidad y así evitar que terminen cerradas.